# AndroidStudio Unambiguous Errors

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've been using AndroidStudio and it has a few inconsistencies but it's very good already.

I've been compiling and running my app fine and then suddenly (after doing something innocuous) it's throwing up the below error but i cannot find out the issue. Does anyone have any ideas how to find out the errors?

> Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 46 sec
>
> 2 errors
>
> 0 warnings
>
> Gradle: 
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':Candle:compileDebug'.
>     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing has really changed in your project settings, then I'd check the log (Help | Show log in Files/Explorer/Finder) for clues. Most likely, the Gradle daemon died, and a rebuild should fix it.

If that doesn't help, then your only option to find more info is to do a command line build. Go to the root of your project, and do:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to get to the errors is to run gradle compile and/or package from the command line. In the root of your project run:

```
gradlew compileDebug
```

AND / OR

```
gradlew packageDebug
```

This will give you command line output for your errors

It also sometimes helps to run a gradle clean before running builds:

```
gradle clean
```

Hope this helps